# I've forget my presale password and i'm trying to recover it with pyethrecover

Tags: recovery, presale

Can someone help me please?
I'm using pyethrecover and i've got this bug when i'm trying to bruteforce with some password : 
[image]

Comment: I expect you fixed your issue looking at the address transactions?